# Vertical spacing in horizontal ChartJS Bar Graph

Tags: javascript, graph, chart.js

I'd like to have more spacing between the bars in my horizontal bar graph. It looks terrible on a mobile device, and barely acceptable on a desktop browser. How can I accomplish this?

*ChartJs Version: 2.4.0*

```
    function renderBarChart(chartDomID, title, labels, dataPoints, barColor) {
    var ctx = document.getElementById(chartDomID).getContext("2d");

    var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'horizontalBar',
        data: {
            labels: labels,
            datasets: [
                {
                    label: title,
                    data: dataPoints,
                    fill: false,
                    pointBorderColor: barColor,
                    backgroundColor: barColor,
                    borderColor: barColor
                }
            ]
        },
        options: {
            responsive: true,
            scales: {
                yAxes: [{
                    display: true,
                    ticks: {
                        // Suggest to start the y-axis at 0, if ChartJS thinks it makes sense.
                        suggestedMin: 0
                    }
                }]
            },
            legend: {
                display: false
            }
        }
    });
```

Mobile View
[image: Mobile View]

Desktop View
[image: Desktop View]

Comment: Increasing the height of Canvas or height of element outside Canvas might help.

Answer (score 2):

You have to add width and height as an example here.

```
<canvas id="myChart" width="700" height="900"></canvas>
```